# Keep all the rows of an Microsoft Word 2010 on the same page

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010

It's so frustrating. I KNEW how to do it (select the rows and click "keep with next") but it doesn't work anymore.

How do I keep all the lines on the same page, causing the table to move to the next page if there's no space left on the current one?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's on the Paragraph toolbar (which is generally on the "Home" tab of the ribbon). Click the tiny arrow in a square on the bottom right hand corner. Choose Line and Page breaks and tick the 'keep with next' box.

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe I didn't find it - I kept looking for the 'paragraph' menu-item in the context menu :(

Comment: A note though. If the paragraph before the table also has the 'keep with next' property, Word will try to fit the table in both pages, instead of the desired effect.